# Showing other subcategories of parent when in subcategory of parent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-lists, custom-taxonomy

I want a simple overview of categories and their subcategories. When clicking the parent category only subcategories of that category are shown. But I also want the subcategories to show when in a different subcategory of the same parent.
I realise the queried_object_id(); changes when clicking on the subcategory. But how do I let the query know?

**My following code:**

```
    <ul>
<?php
        $parentid = get_queried_object_id();
  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 0;

  $args = array(
         'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
         'orderby'      => $orderby,
         'show_count'   => $show_count,
         'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
         'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
         'title_li'     => $title,
         'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );
 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
                                //echo $category_id;
        echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .' - '. $category_id .'</a></li>';
//echo $parentid;
if($parentid == $category_id) {
                                //$cat = get_queried_object();
        $args2 = array(
                'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                'child_of'     => 0,
                'parent'       => $category_id,
                'orderby'      => $orderby,
                'show_count'   => $show_count,
                'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'title_li'     => $title,
                'hide_empty'   => $empty
        );

        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );

        if($sub_cats) {                     
                                    echo '<ul>';
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                                                    //echo $parentid;

               echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .' - '. $sub_category->term_id .'</a></li>';
                                                                //echo  $sub_category->name ;
            }
                                            echo '</ul>';
        }
}                               
    }       
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec you always have miracle solutions when it comes to this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the code based on getting **$parentid2 = get_queried_object();**

**Note:** this code is placed in /woocommerce/archive-product.php

and I added an elseif statement with different args.

Maybe a little bit too much but it works

```
    <ul>
    <?php
      $parentid2 = get_queried_object(); 
      $parentid = get_queried_object_id();
      $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
      $orderby      = 'name';  
      $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
      $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
      $title        = '';  
      $empty        = 0;

      $args = array(
             'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
             'orderby'      => $orderby,
             'show_count'   => $show_count,
             'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
             'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
             'title_li'     => $title,
             'hide_empty'   => $empty
      );
     $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
     foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
            $category_id = $cat->term_id;
            echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a></li>';

    if($parentid == $category_id) {
            $args2 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 0,
                    'parent'       => $category_id,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );

            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );

            if($sub_cats) {                     
                                        echo '<ul>';
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                                                        //echo $parentid;

                   echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a></li>';
                                                                    //echo  $sub_category->name ;
                }
                                                echo '</ul>';
            }
    }

    elseif($parentid2->parent == $category_id) {
            $args2 = array(
                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                    'child_of'     => 0,
                    'parent'       => $parentid2->parent,
                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                    'title_li'     => $title,
                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
            );

            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );

            if($sub_cats) {                     
                                        echo '<ul>';
                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                                                        //echo $parentid;

                   echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a></li>';
                                                                    //echo  $sub_category->name ;
                }
                                                echo '</ul>';
            }
    }



        }       
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont simply use the woocommerce Widget for product categories with Wordpress [`the_widget()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) function, as you will get everything this way:

```
 the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'hierarchical' => true, 'show_children_only' => true )  );
```

It will display a hierarchical vertical list of linked product categories.

> With [`the_widget()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget) function you can with: 
>   - the 2nd parameter argument make changes in the Query 
>   - the 3rd parameter argument make changes in the html output

Comment: the widget works perfect but I want to show the subcategories of the parent category only. And when clicking on a subcategory the menu must stay in tact.

Comment: basically when in the subcategory get the queried_object and use it to compare

Comment: @Solomax I have updated my answer adding , `'show_children_only' => true` to the arguments array… may it's that what you want. Try it again please.

Comment: For some reason 'show_children_only' doesn't work for me. If I insert the widget in a widget area in the control panel it works, but by inserting it programatically using the function "the_widget", setting 'show_children_only' to true (or 1) doesn't change anything. All categories are shown instead of just the sub categories of the current category.

Comment: I figured out that I had to set "hierarchical" to 0 in order for "show_children_only" to work.

Answer (score -1):

you can exclude current category/term by

```
'exclude' => $catID
```

in the arguments.